# RESTful API: как хранить состояние объекта?

Tags: api, rest

Один из принципов RESTful называется "Независимость от состояния (Statelessness)" и в одной статье о нем:

> Первый принцип – независимость от состояния. Проще говоря, RESTful сервер не должен отслеживать, хранить и тем более использовать в работе текущую контекстную информацию о клиенте. С другой стороны клиент должен взять эту задачу на себя. Другими словами не заставляйте сервер помнить состояние мобильного устройства, использующего API.

Теперь вопрос: например, пользователь в игре находится в локации А. Потом он игру запустить завтра в браузере. Естественно, он должен находиться в локации А. Как быть, чтобы хранить это состояние - нахождение в локации исходя из принципа Stateless?

Comment: С одной стороны REST не очень подходит для браузерной игры. С другой - местонахождение персонажа игрока в определенной локации - это не состояние клиента, это состояние бизнес-логики (в данном случае игровой логики). Сохраните его как обычный ресурс, а при следующем подключении пользователь его запросит.

Comment: Я читал эту [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144011/). Там написано, что клиент в запросе должен указать время последнего чтения ленты (feed). Разве это не состояние бизнес-логики?

Comment: Нет, если бизнес-логика заключается в хранении статей, то последняя прочитанная клиентом статья - это скорее свойство клиента.

Comment: И еще, Вы хотите сказать, когда речь идет о состоянии клиента, то не стоит путать его с состоянием бизнес-логики и состоянием ресурса?

Comment: Конечно, о том и речь.

Comment: Спасибо, @Nofate , теперь все стало понятно)

Answer (score 1):

Состояние не запрещается хранить на клиенте. Но всегда есть данные, которые требуют не только клиентской, но и серверной валидации.